# Can anyone explain ravel() in a model

Tags: python, numpy

how does ravel work in a model? even though I know the concept of numpy.ravel, is to reshape the array, but I can't find any documentation for me to learn below.

```
ML_model.fit(features_train,labels_train.values.ravel())
```

Thanks

I just realize something from the documentation,  np.revel(a) is the same as a.revel(), I can break down the code

```
labels_train.values.ravel()
```

, then I understand now

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html

Comment: Attached dup is a slightly different question but has an answer which should be sufficient for your needs.

Comment: I just realize something from the documentation, np.revel(a) is the same as a.revel(), I can break down the code "labels_train.values.ravel()", then I understand now

Comment: `labels_train.values.ravel()` is performed before calling the `fit` method.  It's reshaping one of the input arrays that will be passed to the method.  So apart of knowing that `fit` will accept (or require) a 1d array, this is not `model` specific.